# How to display bar graph on selecting check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have this situation where I have used google charts in my project. The code is as shown below

```
    <html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.gchart.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

            // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
            // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
            // draws it.

            function drawCharts() {

                // Create the data table.
                var dataB = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Chronic Disease', 'Number Of Patients'],
              ['Diabetes', 200],
              ['Hypertension', 84],
              ['Hypercholestrolemia', 76],
              ['Obesity', 48]
                ]);



                // Set chart options
                var optionsB = {
                    title: 'Identified Chronic Population',
                    vAxis: { title: 'Chronic Disease', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red' } }
                };



                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                var chartB = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chartB.draw(dataB, optionsB);

            }
    </script>
</head>
```

---

I have certain checkboxes in html

```
<select id="problems" style="text-align: right">
                <option value="diabetes">DIABETES</option>
                <option value="hypertension">HYPERTENSION</option>
                <option value="hypercholestrolemia">HYPERCHOLESTROLEMIA</option>
                <option value="obesity">OBESITY</option>
            </select>
```

---

I want to display bars corresponding to checkboxes checked. searched over SO and internet but did not get any useful info. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to your `<select>` that will filter the data and redraw the chart when an option is selected.  You would need to add something like this to your chart code:

```
var select = document.querySelector('#problems');
function filterAndDraw (e) {
    if (select.selectedIndex >= 0) {
        var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataB);
        view.setRows(dataB.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, value: value}]));
        chartB.draw(view, optionsB);
    }
    else {
        chartB.draw(dataB, optionsB);
    }
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    select.addEventListener('change', filterAndDraw);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    select.attachEvent('onchange', filterAndDraw);
}
else {
    select.onchange = filterAndDraw;
}
```

To make the filtering work, you have to match the capitalization of the values in the `<option>` elements with the values in the DataTable:

```
<select id="problems" style="text-align: right">
    <option value="Diabetes">DIABETES</option>
    <option value="Hypertension">HYPERTENSION</option>
    <option value="Hypercholestrolemia">HYPERCHOLESTROLEMIA</option>
    <option value="Obesity">OBESITY</option>
</select>
```

see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/y5ZVJ/

There is an easier way to use a dropdown to filter your chart, though: you can use a [CategoryFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter).  See an example based on your chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/y5ZVJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery functionality for this. like

```
$('select option:selected').drawchart(){
//code for the relevant chart.
}
```

Comment: i want to display individual bar pertaining to selection in the same graph. but google charts are predefined !

Comment: you can use html5 canvas element or svg element to create your own barchart.